# Run jar without losing focus

Tags: java, swing

Im using windows task manager to run a .jar every 5 minutes. Its a simple JFrame declared as `public class myClock extends javax.swing.JFrame` that simply shows the actual time (HH:MM).

I have 2 screens: the main screen and the secondary screen.

When the clock runs it starts on the secondary screen on a corner. While watching a movie or playing a game in full screen on main screen, if the task runs, whatever it is on main screen as fullscreen gets minimized, clock displays on secondary screen and gets the focus.

**Is there any way to:**

1. Disable the JFrame of getting the focus on the clock or
2. Lock the focus on the program i chose to avoid getting it minimized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Disable the JFrame of getting the focus on the clock or

When you create your frame you can use:

```
frame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

Comment: damn didnt expect it to be so easy lol. Working as intended now, thanks.